# How to import and transform adjacency matrix to R edge list?

Tags: r, tidyverse, igraph

A sample of my data can be seen below. The data contains information about ties between organizations (over 2000 organizations, the csv file has 0s and 1s, and empty cells)

```
       A2654    B0004   B0188   B1278   B1372   B1722   B2503
A2654   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
B0004   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
B0188   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
B1278   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
B1372   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
B1722   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

(1) The first problem is that I can't import this data (.csv) into R

I runt the following code `dt <- read_csv2("Org_ties.csv")` The problem here is that while in the csv file the first column is left empty (it should be) -- when reading it into R, `read_csv()` generates a label for this column "X1".  I do this in order to run the next code: `g=graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dtmtrx, mode="directed", weighted = T)`  to produce a graph. However, I get the error message below. I think it has to do with the fact that I can't read it properly.

> ```
> graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  : 
>   not a square matrix
> In addition: Warning message:
> In mde(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
> ```

(2) Another puzzling thing is that I cannot seem to transform the current data structure into an edge list. How can I do that? The edge list looks something like this

```
 V1     V2  weight
A2654   B0004   1
A2654   B0188   0
A2654   B1278   0
A2654   B1372   0
A2654   B1722   1
```

Comment: The `readr` functions, like most tidyverse packages, don't keep row names by default. Any reason to not use the base `read.csv` to retain the row names, which you can then convert to a regular column?

Comment: I really don't have any strong reasons more than I've tried to come into the tidy verse world. But also when I try `engo2003<- read.csv("Engo2003.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";") ` the first empty row receives the label "X".

Comment: It's hard to know what the issue is exactly without a sample of the file, but you can rename columns afterwards if that's what you're trying to do. I don't know what you would mean by having an empty column unless it's what would have been row names, but most methods of reading a file into a data frame are going to assign valid names to any columns that don't already have them. Beyond that this would benefit from a [mcve]

Comment: Camille thanks for following up on this. If you copy paste the data sample I provide above in an excellent or csv file, you'll notice that the very first column is empty. And  when I read the csv file that first column gets labeled as "X" or X1" depending on how I read it

Comment: Now this becomes a problem when I try to turn it into a matrix. I am, too, aware that empty columns will be assigned a label. I wonder simply how this can be avoided in order to create a matrix.

Comment: Right, but if the problem is with reading comma-separated text, pasting the output of the table you get *after* reading in comma-separated text doesn't let other people recreate the problem. It's still unclear what the issue is. If you read a column of data that doesn't have a name, it will get one assigned. If you have column names you don't want, you can change them. If you want to convert a column to row names, you can do that. I'm just guessing at this point.